# Ruby on Rails ordenção e relacionamento pais filhos

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tenho uma tabela pai e uma tabela filho, gostaria de saber como faço para fazer uma consulta na tabela filho porem ordenar por uma coluna da tabela pai. Tipo quero saber todos os filhos e ordenar os mesmos pela idade de pai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que exista um relacionamento `has_many/belongs_to` entre o modelo `Pai` e o modelo `Filho`, você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
Filho.includes('pai').order('pais.idade DESC')
```

Pronto, retornará todos os filhos ordenando pela idade do pai.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente :D

Comment: @AndréGava uowww, que bom! :D
precisando estamos ai!